# Fail to download files after storing missing files in list, in different subfolders, Python

Tags: python, server, python-requests, download

I'm trying to create a function to a serverscript to be able to automatically check for some dependencies that the script requires to work as intended, by first checking if the files exist on the filesystem and if not, get them from a webserver. But I cannot really figure out how to proceed. The function looks like this:

```py
folder1 = "Folder1/"
folder2 = "Folder1/Folder2/"

def downloadTxt():
    import os.path
    import requests
    file_repository = "https://ourserver.tld/txtfiles/"
    folderlist = [folder1, folder2]
    for folder in folderlist:
        missing_folders = []
        if not os.path.exists(folder):
            missing_folders.append(folder)
        for folder in missing_folders:
            os.makedirs(folder, exist_ok=True)
            
    filelist = [
        folder1 + "example1.txt",
        folder2 + "example2.txt",
        folder2 + "example3.txt",
        folder2 + "example4.txt",
        ]  # Etc.. I have tons of these files but not really anything useful to show here
    for file in filelist:
        missing_files = []
        if not os.path.exists(file):
            missing_files.append(file)
        for file in missing_files:
            r = requests.get(file_repository + file)
            open(file, "wb").write(r.content)
f_auto_download_txt()
```

This actually creates files named according to the filelist in the correct folders, but the content is just HTML error-messages:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>404 Not Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL was not found on this server.</p>
</body></html>
```

and if I check the webserverlogs I can see that it actually tries to get the files from /webfolder/webfolder/file, which makes sense because of the structure of the filelist.

```
[28/Oct/2021:05:18:30 +0200] "GET /Folder1/Folder1/example1.txt HTTP/1.1" 404 2804 "-" "python-requests/2.26.0"
```

I have tried to "just make it work" even if it's ugly with

```
    missing_files_folder1_stripped = [s.replace(folder1, "") for s in missing_files]
    missing_files_folder2_stripped = [s.replace(folder2, "") for s in missing_files]
    missing_files_all_stripped = missing_files_folder1_stripped + missing_files_folder2_stripped
    for file in missing_files_all_stripped:
        r = requests.get(file_repository + file)
        open(file, "wb").write(r.content)
```

but with no success, I managed to get one of the files, supposed to be in Folder1, downloaded to the rootdirectory, and when it reaches the first file in Folder2, I get "couldn't find Folder2\example2.txt. The server even gives me a HTTP code 200 so it looks like it should have worked, but no. So my other plan was to just get all the files downloaded to whatever directory and sort it afterwards, but now I'm stuck even getting the files downloaded properly at all.

Would appreciate any working solution to this, thanks on beforehand!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this after inspecting the accesslog of the webserver a little better, looking for what files that was actually asked for by the script, and I found out that I still had some errors in the filestructure. What I ended up doing was creating a new, "clean" list of the files with Folder1 stripped out of it, and changed the parameters of the open-function, so now it works as intended.

```
    new_list_clean = [s.replace(folder1, "") for s in missing_files]
    
    for file in new_list_clean:
        r = requests.get(file_repository + file)
        open(folder1 + file, "wb").write(r.content)
```

Also it may or may not give you a permission-error, in my case I just made sure to have write-access to that folder on my test-machine (which run's Windows), but it may be useful to set

```
os.makedirs(folder, exist_ok=True, mode=0760)  # Example for giving fileowner full access and group read+write
```

right away to don't have this problem on *nix systems.